# SQL exception not handled in WebService

Tags: java, sql, web-services, exception

We developed the stateless Web-service implementation. We used JPA as ORM layer to do the database operations. In service methods, we used the Entity Manager to persist the entity. while persisting the same record into the table, we are not able to handle those exception `"Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TIGOSUSCRIPTIONES.SYS_C0020549) violated" exception in Service method. It is directly throwing the following exception in client result.`

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Transaction rolled back 
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178) 
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111) 
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108) 
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78) 
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107) 
at $Proxy30.registerSaleOutcome(Unknown Source)
```

How to handle this exception. Following is the code we used in service method business logic.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) 
public void recycleOperation(Recycle recycle) throws RecycleFault_Exception{ 
   try{ 
     em.persist(recycle); 
   } catch(Exception e){ 
     //not coming to this block 
     log.error("Exception in Data Insertion:"+e.getMessage()); 
     RecycleFault fault = new RecycleFault(); 
     fault.setErrorCode("101"); 
     fault.setMessage("Record is already Existed"); 
     RecycleFault_Exception faultExp = new RecycleFault_Exception("RecycleFault Exception", fault); 
     throw faultExp; 
   } 
}
```

Could you help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `em.persist(recycle);` then your `recycle` object is attached with your EntityManager. This does not mean that `recycle` object is inserted (persisted) into the database immediately. EntityManager inserts `recycle` object into the database when the ongoing transaction is committed. It looks like your `public void recycleOperation` method is Transactional. This implies that the EntityManager inserts the `recycle` object after finishing the execution of `recycleOperation` method. Hence, the Exception you are seeing originated when the execution of `recycleOperation` method is finished.

Long story short, you should catch the exception in the method where `recycleOperation` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for reply.How to handle exception if this method web service method and invoked by client request?

Comment: @AnılEmreÖzçelik, are you using Spring REST? Then you can use `@ExceptionHandler` to handle top-level exceptions. Details: http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: I am using SOAP web services.